# Properly install redis on centos7 vm

Tags: redis, centos, centos7

I want to configure redis more properly on my vm. I a tutorial here : https://redis.io/topics/quickstart under `Installing Redis more properly`. I followed it very carefully. However, when I nearly met the end of the tutorial, I found that I cannot run `sudo update-rc.d redis_6379 defaults` to add `redis_6379` to runlevels. I searched on the internet. Some peoples says using `sudo chkconfig --add redis_6379` or `systemctl enable redis_6379` but neither worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial describes an installation on an older Debian or Ubuntu. There are no runlevels on CentOS 7; instead you have to use Systemd:

```
systemctl status|enable|disable|start|stop|restart redis
```